# sql get name of day and count it

Tags: sql-server

i'm Fajar from indonesia, i have the problem to create report with sql server.
I have a transaction table as below,

```
Date       | Trx_ID| Member_id| Invt_id |Branch_id
01-01-2013 | tr001 | 0002     | invt002 |br001
01-01-2013 | tr001 | 0002     | invt003 |br001
01-01-2013 | tr001 | 0002     | invt004 |br001
01-03-2013 | tr002 | 0001     | invt001 |br001
01-03-2013 | tr002 | 0001     | invt003 |br001
01-04-2013 | tr003 | 0003     | invt002 |br001
01-04-2013 | tr003 | 0003     | invt004 |br001
01-05-2013 | tr004 | 0002     | invt005 |br001
01-05-2013 | tr004 | 0002     | invt006 |br001
01-05-2013 | tr005 | 0005     | invt004 |br001
01-05-2013 | tr005 | 0005     | invt005 |br001
01-05-2013 | tr005 | 0005     | invt006 |br001
01-06-2013 | tr006 | 0001     | invt001 |br001
01-06-2013 | tr006 | 0001     | invt002 |br001
```

and i want to create report like this

```
Branch_id| weekdays | weekend|weekdays_Weekend
br001    |  2       | 1      | 2
```

its mean group by the member_id. and if member doing transaction on weekend counts it on weekdays, if member doing transaction on weekdays count it too on weekend, but if member doing transaction on weekdays and weekend count it on weekdays_weekend.
weekend are : Saturday and Sunday
weekdays are : Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday
weekdays_weekend if the member doing transaction more than 1 and doing on weekend and weekdays

this is wrong query when i try

```
select
  max(branch_id)
, count(DISTINCT trx_id)
, sum(case when datename(dw,date) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday') then f.trx_id else null end) AS 'WeekDays'
, sum(case when datename(dw,date) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Weekend'
, sum(case when datename(dw,date) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday') then 1 else 0 end) as 'Weekdays_weekend'
from Transaction

where branch_id = '14067' and convert (char(6), date, 112) = '201301'
group by branch_id
```

the Result not group with trx_id and member_id

```
Branch_id|weekdays|weekend|weekdays_weekend
br001    | 7      | 7     | 0
```

i'm sorry if my english is bad
please help me to create the report

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what are the problems you encountered?
Can you show the sql you've already got?

Comment: SQL server is not oracle. Oracle is not SQL Server

Comment: thaks for correction podiluska

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't understand whatr you meean by counting on weekdays_weekend but bewlow is query to check total transaction on Weekends or Weekdays

```
SELECT branch_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,[Date]) NOT IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as weekdays,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,[Date])  IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as weekend
FROM tableName
GROUP BY branch_id
```

DATEPART() function extracts day of week when dw is passed to to it. Values returned are 1 to 7 , Saturday is 7 ,Sunday is 1

Comment: hy m hasan, how about the member where come more than 1 and come on weekdays and weekend?